# Consensus? MySQL, Signed VS Unsigned Primary/Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, integer, primary-key, unsigned, signed

I have seen a couple threads about what everyone was doing now a days in regards to signed vs unsigned key values. It would seem that unsigned is optimal since it allows twice the number of rows for the same cost. Are there any benefits with signed keys?

Is there any standard consensus? Its seems like signed is the answer since "it has always been that way"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer to set my columns as `unsigned` if they cannot be negative. Besides the range factor that you mentioned, it also makes it clearer when reading the table definition.

Answer (score -2):

A signed 32-bit int can represent over 2 billion numbers so I suspect the issue is moot for most people. That said, I often use negative numbers when I want to indicate that a record is purposefully orphaned.

Comment: GAHH! Sorry, I work with an application where someone (no longer with the company) thought this would be a good idea. Literally, at least once a week, we find some kind of issue (either challenge with new code, or bug in existing code) caused by this crazy design decision. **You should not give primary keys meaning beyond the key value itself, and you should never change primary key values**. If you want to indicate soft-delete, have a status column or a softDeleted column. Because it was in a fundamental piece of the software, we're only just now fixing it, as part of a major rewrite.

Comment: @gregmac s'ok, I knew it would be controversial. Quite ironically, a better word that 'orphan' would have been 'existential'. It was an ironic choice of terms since I came up with the scheme in order to represent people that I only knew must exist. My application allows a user to say that Bob and Charlie are brothers but internally stored them has records whose parent(s) columns both referenced records with negative keys. If someone added Jane as Bob's mom I could update Charlie as well. Generally I use the pattern when I want to say that there exists some thing that other things must be near.

Comment: Also, I'm very familiar with the doctrine that primary keys should not have meaning. A better maxim is that meaning should be encapsulated. PK's should not mean anything to the application layer but they do mean things to the database (management system) itself. In the scheme that I described above I'm simply using the PKs as metadata. Incidentally, I discussed this here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023988/modeling-existential-facts-in-a-relational-database

Comment: Using negative numbers to indicate orphaned is a bad practice. Implicit behavior, even when documented, leads to confusing code. Not only that, if you're using a surrogate key, such as in this case, the surrogate key's meaning should be nothing other than a row identity. Incidentally as well, if you do for some reason exceed 2B records, you'll start inserting rows with negative values and your application's behavior will be wrong. This is bad all around.